# While converting String to Date got ambiguity between java.util.Date and java.sql.Date

Tags: java, date, ambiguity, date-conversion

I am trying to get date as input from Date tag of HTML

`Birth Date <input type="date"  name="dob"/>`

and accessing on jsp page by using

```
String strDate = request.getParameter("dob");
```

but it returns in the format of string and I wanted to convert it in to date, I have tried as follows

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = sdf.parse(strDate);
```

But it gives error

> incompatible types required: java.sql.Date found:    java.util.Date

and when I imported pakage "java.util.*"   for using   `java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(strDate);` it gives

> reference to Date is ambiguous, both class java.util.Date in java.util and class java.sql.Date in java.sql match

Comment: You probably still have `java.sql.Date` imported. Remove it and the error will go away.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a `java.sql.Date` (and *incompatible types required: java.sql.Date found: java.util.Date* indicates you do), remove the import of `java.util.Date` and use the `java.util.Date` returned by the `DateFormat` to construct a `java.sql.Date` with something like

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
    Date date = new Date(sdf.parse(strDate).getTime());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( "2018-01-23" )
```

## Details

The [Answer by Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36224660/642706) is correct. One comment there asked if is there is a better conversion recommended. There is indeed a better way. Bonus: that better way avoids the original problem, confusing `java.util.Date` with `java.sql.Date`.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later supplants the poorly-designed troublesome old `java.util.Date`/`.Calendar` classes and their kin. The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). See the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. Back-ported to Java 6 & 7 by the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, which is wrapped for use in [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) by the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

The [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.

## ISO 8601

Your input string happens to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

This standard is used by default in the java.time classes for parsing/generating date-time strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2016-01-23" );
```

## Database

As of [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2 and later, you can exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database via `getObject`/`setObject` methods.

### JDBC 4.2 and later

Insert/Update.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , localDate ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate localDate = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

### JDBC 4.1 and earlier

If your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) is not yet updated for JDBC 4.2 or later, convert between java.time and java.sql types. The old java.sql classes have new methods for such conversions.

For `LocalDate`, convert to/from the [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) class (which pretends to be a date-only value).

```
java.sql.Date mySqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( localDate );
```

…and going the other direction…

```
java.time.LocalDate localDate = mySqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).